# Программа не выводит считанные из файла символы в консоль

Tags: c, файлы, циклы

Задача: считать некоторое количество символов из файла, сделано по книге, код сверил, тем не менее вывода в консоль нет

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char ch[100];

    if((fp=fopen("/Users/user_name/Desktop/C/for_read.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("Open err.");
        return 1;
    }

    fread(ch,sizeof ch, 1 , fp);

    for(int i=0;i<0;i++) printf("%c ",ch[i]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста.  Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Цикл с условием `for(int i=0;i<0` не выполняется ни разу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотелось бы понять, что вы ожидаете от кода

```
for(int i = 0; i < 0;
```

Итак, инициализация. `i` получает нулевое значение. Проверка - меньше ли `i` нуля. Нет? Нуль не меньше нуля? Значит, выходим из цикла и идем к следующей строке - закрываем файл и завершаем работу программы...